# How to generate unique id with prefix using Spring Data Couchbase SDK?

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I would like to know how to generate a unique id with prefix e.g. **user::524525** with Couchbase SDK.

When I started with Couchbase [using the Couchbase JavaSDK guide](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/start-using-sdk.html#java-using-sdk), I noticed that in all the examples the id looks like TYPE::ID e.g user::king_arthur. This is also recommended to avoid conflicting ids for different documents. As I was reading the [documentation from Spring Data Couchbase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#couchbase.autokeygeneration.usingattributes) I thought the way to do it would be

```
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.id.GeneratedValue;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.id.GenerationStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.id.IdPrefix;
import com.couchbase.client.java.repository.annotation.Id;
...

@Data
public class User {    

    @IdPrefix
    private String prefix = "user";

    @Id @GeneratedValue(delimiter = "::", strategy = GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES)
    private String id;
}
```

but when I test this and check in the db, the ID is just "user".

Am I missing something? Is it a bug? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So actually I found the answer, I had to use **GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE** like this:

```
@IdPrefix
private String prefix = "user";

@Id @GeneratedValue( delimiter = "::", strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
private String id;
```

which generates a unique id like user::8a9gfa4d55f7.

The JavaDoc is confusing though, because for GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES it explicitly says it will use the prefix:

> Constructs key from the entity attributes using the supplied id,
>   prefix, suffix

but not for GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE:

> Uses an uuid generator